# I am making a music app, how to update/calculate plays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, express

I am making a music app and I want to update the plays each time user plays the song for 30sec, but I can't create a logic for it. I tried doing this:

```
        let current_final;
        let current_inital;
        
        this.audio.addEventListener("play", (e)=>{
            current_inital = this.audio.currentTime
        })
        this.audio.addEventListener("pause", (e)=>{
            current_final = this.audio.currentTime
            this.updateViews(current_inital, current_final)
        })
        this.audio.addEventListener("ended", (e)=>{
            current_final = this.audio.currentTime
            this.updateViews(current_inital, current_final)
        })
        
        
  updateViews(initialTime, finalTime)
    {
        const url = "/api/music/views/update"
        const data = 
        {
            info:{
                initialTime: initialTime,
                finalTime: finalTime,
            },
            track: this.song
        }
        this.postData(url, data)
    }
```

Each time the user plays the song, the initial time gets recorded, and each time the user pauses the song, the final time gets recorded and gets sent to my server,

My server:

```
function update_views(track, info)
{
    const intialTime = info.initialTime;
    const finalTime = info.finalTime;
    if(finalTime - intialTime > 30){
        const current_views = track.stats.views;
        const updated_views = current_views+1;
        db.ref("users/"+track.info.userID+"/public/songs/"+track.info.songID+"/stats").update({
            views: updated_views
        })
    }
}   



router.post("/update", (req, res)=>{
    const track = req.body.track;
    const info = req.body.info;
    update_views(track, info)
    res.end("success")
})
```

The function checks if the difference between initial and final time is greater than 30sec, if it is then it updates the views by 1.

I tried doing this but I don't think this is a good way of doing it. I think users can abuse this.

Comment: I suppose it begins with you defining what *actually* constitutes a "play" of a song. Seems you've settled on playing 30 seconds of it. What is your concern. Try to be as specific as possible about any issues or concerns.

Comment: @DrewReese i want the plays to updated if users plays it for more than 30sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On "play" event "**setTimeout**" for 30 seconds or 30 seconds - current time, so if the video is at the 17 seconds currently we will send call "*updateViews*" function after 13 seconds(30 - 17 = 13), just make sure you are handling the cases when the user skip the song before the 30 seconds or the song has ended for this you can use "**clearTimeout**".
I haven't tested the code, so have it in mind, I'm just giving you one way of solving the problem, but of  course you have to dig deeper I guess.
So if you need a working and tested solution, just write a comment, so I can delete it!

```
let current_final;
let current_inital;
let callApiWithDelay;
let areViewsUpdated = false;

this.audio.addEventListener("play", (e)=>{
    current_inital = this.audio.currentTime
    if(!areViewsUpdated) {
      callApiWithDelay = setTimeout(() => {
        updateViews(current_inital, this.audio.currentTime)
        areViewsUpdated = true;
      }, 30000 - this.audio.currentTime)
    }
})
this.audio.addEventListener("pause", (e)=>{
    current_final = this.audio.currentTime
    this.updateViews(current_inital, current_final)
    clearTimeout(callApiWithDelay)
})
this.audio.addEventListener("ended", (e)=>{
    current_final = this.audio.currentTime
    this.updateViews(current_inital, current_final)
    clearTimeout(callApiWithDelay)
})
```